# ListBox or DropDown or Spinner of images in iOS

Tags: ios, drop-down-menu, listbox, spinner

Is there any way to select an **image** from a list, using something like `spinner` or `dropDown` or `listBox`?
Here is an example in android:

[image]

How can I do this in ios?

Comment: You could use the following [library](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown)

Comment: What would stop you from using a TableView/CollectionView to do this?